# Modal Popup will not show if i do ajax-based paging inside my WebGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor, webgrid

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application, and i am facing a problem as jquery is not loading if i do ajax paging inside my webgrid. 
I got the following.The main view which have the grid:-

```
    @model SkillManagement.Models.PagedList<SkillManagement.Models.Phone>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Phone List";
    }

    <h1>Phone List</h1>
    <div class="well">
       @using (Html.BeginForm("index", null, FormMethod.Get))
        {

            <div style="margin-top:17px;">
                @{
                var grid = new WebGrid(
                            canPage: true,
                            rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                            canSort: true,
                            ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

                grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
                grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

                @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
                fillEmptyRows: false,
                tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                columns: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column("PhoneId", "ID"),
                 //code goes here
                  grid.Column(header: "Action", canSort: false, style: "action",
                    format: @<text>
                       @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/details/" + item.PhoneId + "' id='" + item.PhoneId + "' title='Detail'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> </span> </a>")
                       @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/edit/" + item.PhoneId + "' id='" + item.PhoneId + "' title='Edit'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> </a>")
                       @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/delete/" + item.PhoneId + "' id='" + item.PhoneId + "' title='Delete'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span> </a>")
                    </text>)

                ));
                }


            </div>
        }
    </div>


    <!-- modal placeholder-->
    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id='myModalContent'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/appjs/phones.js")
}
```

and the _partial view which will be rendered as a modal popup:-

```
@model SkillManagementTDMGroup.Models.Phone

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Phone</h3>
    </div>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.PhoneId)

        <div class="modal-body">

           //code goes here...
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    }
    <script>
        $("form").removeData("validator");
        $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
    </script>
```

and here is the phones.js:-

```
$(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');

                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });


    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            var isValid = true; // assume all OK
            $('form').validate(); // perform validation on the form
            $('input[type="text"]').each(function (index, item) { // could change selector to suit e.g $('input, textarea').each(..            
                if (!$(this).valid()) {
                    isValid = false; // signal errors
                    return false; // break out of loop   
                }
            })
            if (!isValid) {
                return false; // exit
            }
            $('#progress').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#progress').hide();
                        //location.reload();
                        alert(result.message);
                    } else {

                        $('#progress').hide();
                        $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

now when i visit the main view the modal popup will work well, but if i do some paging inside the webgrid and i click to render the partial view as modal popup i will get the following exception :-

```
Unhandled exception at line 51, column 9 in http://localhost:58652/phone/edit/3

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

on the following Script section inside the partial view:-

```
<script>
            $("form").removeData("validator");
            $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
        </script>
```

Comment: That error generally means jquery-##.js is not included in the main page

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes i know this is related to jquery, but i am already loading the jQuery inside the _layout view before the RenderBody() method. and as i mentioned when i first visit the webGrid the partial view that is rendered as modal popup will show without any problem, but when i do ajax-based paging on the grid and i try to open the modal popup again i will ge tthe error. could this be becuase jquery is not able to regonize the new DOM which is rendered when doing paging ... can u adivce ?

Comment: I don't think its got anything to do which _recognizing the new DOM_. `'$' is undefined` means the jquery is not loaded. Do you have the file defined more that one (e.g in a partial view as well as the layout which can cause problems)?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed and worked fine for me....

"Modal Popup will not show if i do ajax-based paging inside my WebGrid"

**OR**

"When navigate to 2nd page and click on edit, delete or view it is displaying normal page instead of displaying it in modal pop up".

**Change code in phones.js:**

From

```
$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
```

To

```
$(document).on("click","a[data-modal]", function (e) {
```

Enjoy coding................